# Error when segueing to view controller with Table View from Textfield in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, tableview, sigabrt

Okay let me explain the issue I had. In main.storyboard, I created a new tableView controller and added a navigation bar to the top. I created the segue to the new tableView controller, and everything worked fine. The problem was the navigation bar does not stay at the top when scrolling through the table. After searching the internet, most people say, just create a normal ViewController and add a Table View to it, and then add the navigation bar etc. So I did that, but now, when ever you press in the textfield, the app just crashes, And displays:

```
Thread 1: signal SIGABRT next to the line: class AppDelegate:
UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate.
```

I cannot figure out for the life of me why this, and I'm new to swift and code in general so wondering if i am the one at error. To test whether the issue lines in my code elsewhere, I have created a a brand new Xcode project to re create this scenario. But I run into the exact same error, which makes me think it's not the rest of my code.

So, here's my new basic Xcode project code to show what I'm trying to do.

**View controller**:

```
Import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    textField.delegate = self
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {

    performSegueWithIdentifier("countryTableView", sender: self)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

**TableViewController**:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var countryPicker = ["Uk", "Germany", "Colombia", "Spain"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return countryPicker.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    cell.textLabel!.text = countryPicker[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
}
```

I have linked the datasource and delegate of the table View to the View Controller. And as far as I'm concerned, I've done everything else.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your code you posted here. I think you have UIViewController in storyboard and the class you assigned to it is UITableViewController. Is that the case?

Comment: are you using navigation controller?

Comment: @MAbdulSami Yeah that's exactly the case. And no I'm not using a navigation controller.

Comment: You need to assign UIViewController class to UIViewController in storyboard. And then add protocols for UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate in you UIViewController class you assigned. And then also create a new referencing outlet of your tableView to your class (i.e. ctrl+drag from storyboard).

Comment: and you should use navigation controller , with that you will not have issue with navigation bar

Comment: @MAbdulSami Hi, Okay so i've done what you said above and it makes no difference. It still crashes with the same error I mentioned above. So I created a new VC, created a new file of subclass TableViewController, and I linked the class to it. I've updated the code above for the tableView Controller. Does it all look and sound right to you? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text says you've created UIViewController in your storyboard and added a UITableView to it (if I'm reading it correctly). But your `TableViewController` is a `UITableViewController` subclass, not a `UIViewController` subclass. That's probably the cause of the crash.

Change the superclass to a `UIViewController` and add a `UITableView` `IBOutlet`:

```
@IBOutlet private weak var tableView: UITableView!
```

Don't forget to wire it up in the storyboard.

Also, some code cleanup might help...

---

Don't assign the `textField`'s delegate in code. Do that in Interface Builder. Less code is better.

---

Next, remove all of the `-didReceiveMemoryWarning` code. You're not using it, so it's just cluttering up your code, and it's cluttering up your question here.

Whenever you see this pattern of a method just calling super, it can be safely removed and the behavior won't be affected. For example, you can also remove it in the `-viewDidLoad` method of the `TableViewController` class.

---

Remove these comments:

```
// #warning Incomplete method implementation.
// Return the number of rows in the section.
```

That's from Xcode's template. It's to help you out, but don't leave junk in your code. And again, it's not useful here on Stack Overflow.

---

Let's fix your `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` call. It's not right.You're creating a new cell each time, rather than reusing cells. Do this instead:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("UITableViewCell") as! UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel!.text = countryPicker[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Make sure you have a prototype cell in the table view in the storyboard. It should be of type `UITableViewCell` and have an identifier of "UITableViewCell".

---

Comment: Thanks, that all seemed to have worked! The only thing it's doing, is when I'm pressing in the textField, it show the keyboard and then segues to the tableView. How can I stop that? I want it to go straight to the tableView Controller. Thanks

Comment: It's doing that because touching a textField normally allows you to enter text in the field. What you're doing is not what users are going to expect. However, you can probably overcome it by returning false from the -textFieldShouldBeginEditing: delegate method and performing the segue there.

Comment: thanks so much that worked! And thanks for the advice with the rest of the code!